# Find in value elasticsearch Response

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have merged `list` of ids. I want to do it on one search.

I am doing `ES search` like:

```
self._test_search.with_ids(idsWithOtherIds).search()
```

Then I am `iterating` over one 1st part:

```
for test in tests:
    if test.id in ids:
```

But in this for loop I need to get some data from other part of results.

How can I do it ?

EDIT:

```
idsWithVectorsCids = idsForVectors + ids
```

and in for loop I need to take result from ES from idsForVectors.

Comment: Which data do you  need from other part of result? Could you post a sample of your code?

Comment: edited for more info

Comment: I need to do like in scala results.find(_.id == neededId) I am new to python :)